# How to handle unverified accounts with spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created a User Registration module with Spring MVC and Spring Security.  When the account is created, I set a my own state for the user of "Unverified".  The account is verified after the user clicks on the link provided in the email.  The user has to be logged in for the verification to occur.

What is the best practice for handling the case where the user does not verify the email address, but still logs into the system.  Do you always display a "unverified" account page and prevent the user from navigating else where?  Can this be done-- how?  The other option, I thought would be to restrict functions but still allow user to browse the site.

To achieve first case, I think I would use my own filters?
For second case, do I need dynamic roles to restrict access?

Looking from some expert advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion is to add a role for users that have verified, for example `ROLE_VERIFIED`. Protect URL:s with this role. Have a [access denied handler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html) that can tell if the user needs to verify the account (the handler will be hit when the role is required but missing).

Config can look something like:

```xml
<http>
  <intercept-url pattern="/pagesforverified/**" access="ROLE_VERIFIED" />
  <access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler" />
  <!-- rest of configuration -->
</http>
```

Gotcha: When adding role to a user that is logged in, the security context will not update automatically, since it is cached in the session.

Comment: Sounds simple enough.  I will try it out.  Thanks.